# Event for when an element is added/removed from the DOM, without knowing the parent element

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a function similar to this:

```
function makeSomeElement() {
    const out = document.createElement("div");
    // do some things with out

    // pseudo code for what I am looking for
    out.onadded = () => { ... }
    out.onremoved = () => { ... }

    return out;
}
```

As you can see the function knows nothing about the parent element.

As far as I know `MutationObserver` only observer child elements, attributes and text.

Basically I want to execute a function every time `out` is added or removed from the DOM. I feel like I have missed something painfully obvious.

The only solution I see, is making a [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) class with the functions `connectedCallback` and `disconnectedCallback`. That seems a lot more complicated that it should be.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm intrigued when you say you don't know the parent. Surely when you append the element to the DOM you know where you're putting it, ergo, what its parent is. Additionally, mutation observer can be configured to monitor descendant elements, not just children, via the [`substree`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/subtree) param.

Comment: I might be able to pass a the parent as a parameter, but that doesn't account for cases where the element is removed an then added to a different element, thus changing the parent.
What's the difference between descendant and children? Here https://jsfiddle.net/RaiderB/wq8yxhgv/ you can see that the observer doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Descendant means children and children of children. I'm no expert on the MO API but looking at the docs for `subtree` it certainly suggests a deeper level than just children.

Comment: I see, but I don't care about the children, just that one element. I don't want to observe `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

i think your best shot would be using mutation observer on its parent

you have a point here though, it make sense to have events on adding/deleting nodes. unfortunately there is no events fired with these operations yet.

when you connect a node with a parent, its changing isConnected flag of the node to be true or false and thats it.

From https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/dom/Node.h

```
// Called *after* this node or its ancestor is inserted into a new parent (may or may not be a part of document) by scripts or parser.
// insertedInto **MUST NOT** invoke scripts. Return NeedsPostInsertionCallback and implement didFinishInsertingNode instead to run scripts.
virtual InsertedIntoAncestorResult insertedIntoAncestor(InsertionType, ContainerNode& parentOfInsertedTree);
virtual void didFinishInsertingNode() { }
```

From https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/dom/Node.cpp

```
Node::InsertedIntoAncestorResult Node::insertedIntoAncestor(InsertionType insertionType, ContainerNode& parentOfInsertedTree)
{
    if (insertionType.connectedToDocument)
        setNodeFlag(NodeFlag::IsConnected);
    if (parentOfInsertedTree.isInShadowTree())
        setNodeFlag(NodeFlag::IsInShadowTree);

    invalidateStyle(Style::Validity::SubtreeAndRenderersInvalid);

    return InsertedIntoAncestorResult::Done;
}

void Node::removedFromAncestor(RemovalType removalType, ContainerNode& oldParentOfRemovedTree)
{
    if (removalType.disconnectedFromDocument)
        clearNodeFlag(NodeFlag::IsConnected);
    if (isInShadowTree() && !treeScope().rootNode().isShadowRoot())
        clearNodeFlag(NodeFlag::IsInShadowTree);
    if (removalType.disconnectedFromDocument) {
        if (auto* cache = oldParentOfRemovedTree.document().existingAXObjectCache())
            cache->remove(*this);
    }
}
```